# Why does my Jekyll site show HUGE icons on Github Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

1. I generated a new jekyll site with `jekyll new simple-site`
2. The site looks ok in the localhost. It's the default, dummy site that's generated anyways.
3. I pushed it to `gh-pages` branch of a repo.

Now the site shows up under github.io/ but with HUGE icons.

The svg icons for github and twitter in the default jekyll generated site span the whole width of the page. They should be 16px or so.

Similarly 3 huge blocks appear in the top. They, again, are svg, which are supposed to be thin lines.

Here's my site: http://ananthp.github.io/carnatic_scores/
(repo: https://github.com/ananthp/carnatic_scores/tree/gh-pages )

[image: HUGE svg icons in github pages jekyll site]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As your site is not at the root of the domain ananthp.github.io/ but in a "directory" carnatic_scores/, you have to set `baseurl` variable in your _config.yml file.

```
baseurl: '/carnatic_scores'
```

Edit: some explanations

In _includes/head.html you can see this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

which is equivalent to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/main.css">
```

With `baseurl` set to **""** (default) your relative url is **/css/main.css**, which is resolved as **http://ananthp.github.io/css/main.css** by your browser = 404 not found.

With `baseurl` set to **"/carnatic_scores"** your relative url is **/carnatic_scores/css/main.css**, which is resolved as **http://ananthp.github.io/carnatic_scores/css/main.css** by your browser = your cool css !

That's true for all assets (css, js and image) :

```
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/path_to_scripts/script.js"></script>

<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/path_to_images/image.jpg">

or in markdown

![Image alt]({{ site.baseurl }}/path_to_images/image.jpg)
```

Comment: That fixes it. So, was the lack of baseurl prevented the stylesheet from loading?

Comment: @DavidJacquel  Any idea about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34532476/2404470)

Answer (score 1):

David Jacquel's answer is correct but I wanted to point out that Jekyll has [a page about how to properly setup your Jekyll site for github pages](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-pages). On that site they specifically talk about the fix (changing `baseurl`) but they mention other important things that you have to know too such as previewing your site with

```
$ jekyll serve --baseurl ''
```

Good luck and happy blogging!