# Showing C# <summary> tags in Jekyll Github pages using Highlight.js

Tags: javascript, c#, jekyll, highlight, github-pages

To show [codes successfully with simple HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11811335/2404470), I have added [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org) in my [Jekyll based blog](http://xameeramir.github.io/) which is running on [Github pages](https://pages.github.com)

```html
<!--Add Highlight.js https://highlightjs.org/download/ -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.0.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.0.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

<!-- Using Highight.js https://highlightjs.org/usage/-->
<script>
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
```

I need to show the below **C# code** i.e. everything between `<pre> <code class="csharp">` and `</code> </pre>`:

```
<pre>
<code class="csharp">

/// <summary>
/// Main class of the project
/// </summary>
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main entry point of the program
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Command line args</param>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}

</code>
</pre>
```

This code is added in [this `.md` file](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2015-11-22-vs-documentation.md) which is [displayed here](http://xameeramir.github.io/vs-documentation/).

Everything is getting rendered, except [`<summary>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx) tags. *Is [the Highlighter](https://highlightjs.org/) misunderstanding it as normal HTML?*

## Question:

How do a developer make sure that everything between `<pre> <code class="csharp">` and `</code> </pre>` including that [`<summary>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx) tag is displayed using [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) in such scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`code` HTML Tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element) uses [Phrasing Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) which means it will treat regular HTML Tags such as `<summary>` as regular HTML Code and therefore omits the output.

To avoid this problem you'd have to properly encode all tags:

```
<pre>
<code class="csharp">

    /// &lt;summary&gt;
    /// Summary description for the function or property goes here
    /// &lt;/summary&gt;

</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: This was perfect and helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Jekyll has highlight tag and css (`_sass/_syntax-highlighting.scss`) onboard.

```
{% highlight csharp %}
/// <summary>
/// Main class of the project
/// </summary>
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main entry point of the program
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Command line args</param>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
{% endhighlight %}
```

This works out of the box with no need to client side overload.
All Pygment lexers available are [here](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/).

Comment: +3 this is cool! I am much concerned with server than client ;)