# Why is the code formatting not working on this highlighted generated jekyll page?

Tags: javascript, jekyll, highlight, code-formatting, github-pages

In my [gh-page](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2016-6-30-what-is-silverlight.md), the [code formatting tags are properly encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34532476/2404470).

`&lt; tag name goes here &gt;`

Corresponding `<pre>` and `<code>` tags are enclosed.
I believe this is the reason, the [preview](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2016-6-30-what-is-silverlight.md) renders without any issue.

[image: Github page preview renders perfectly]

However on the [resulting page UI](http://xameeramir.github.io/what-is-silverlight/), the code highlighting breaks after `# Dependency property system - DPS`.

[image: UI breaks on Github page]

I'm using [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/)

This seems to be a kind of [bug](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/issues/1269) to me.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: This is an interesting one. There's obviously a difference between how Github Markdown and Jekyll is being processed. Have you tried running the site on Jeykll locally? do you see the same issue?

Comment: @StephenG - no man, there seems to be no effect :(

Comment: Looks like the syntax highlighting is working. Did you fix it?

Comment: Nope, I [removed the code part](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/commit/660193c7b1ed58d8241ff983a474f220f0ff646e) from the blog entry :(. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I agree with @Ross. The syntax highlighting looks fine to me. Can you take screenshots showing exactly what you're saying is broken?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - I'll revert back to old version and will share the screen shots.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Check the updated code and question. The issue is reproduced :(

Comment: Took a look at it today. Looks like highlight.js bug to me too, I agree

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [isagalaev](https://github.com/isagalaev).

It's a bug, but not in highlight.js. Here's an excerpt of the relevant part of page source:

```
<pre><code>
namespace abcLib
{
  public class LatinWords : IMarkupExtension<string>
 ...
}&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;
```

There are two problems with it:

- You probably wanted  displayed as is, so you have to escape it as `&lt;string&gt;`
- It looks like `&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;` was supposed to actually end this code snippet, so they should not be escaped: `</code></pre>`
  I don't know what kind of software generates this HTML, so I can't give any particular recommendations on how to fix those two problems. But they most certainly have nothing to do with highlighting, it's just HTML.